# py2app selenium without firefox install

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, py2app

I am wondering if there is a way within py2app to include the Firefox browser, or if there is a way for Selenium to use Firefox without having to install Firefox on the host machine.

I have created an app with py2app that uses Selenium, however, I have Firefox installed on my machine, but not everyone that will receive the app will have Firefox installed. I am looking for a way to either include Firefox in the distribution or go around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script will not run if `Firefox` is not preinstalled.
You can test your script with other browser, for example Chrome. If it works on Chrome also, then you can edit script like this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
except WebDriverException:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

You can add same for few more browsers (IE, Opera, Safari...) to be sure that script will run on users machine

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.